# Map iterator error on class assignment

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, iterator

I have an error in map iterators. The problem is the following:

```
class JacobianCol
{
private:
...
    JacobianColData::iterator _L_begin;
public:
    JacobianColData::iterator L_begin();
...
};
```

In another module:

```
JacobianCol LUSolver::col_subtract(const JacobianColData::iterator &alpha, JacobianCol &X, JacobianCol &Y)
{
    JacobianCol result = Y;

    //alternate "result" variable

    return result;
}
```

Call:

```
...
J[*it] = col_subtract(friend_element, J[diag_index], J[*it]);
...
```

And when I assign result of `col_subtract` to `J[*it]` I get `J[*it].L_begin` pointing to a deallocated memory (pointer to a previous `J[*it]`).

Comment: Not solving your issue, but names with beginning underscore followed by an uppercase letter as well as names beginning with double-underscores are reserved for the C++ implementation.

Comment: thanks. I use underscores to distinct private, protected from public. I'll consider your recommendation in the future projects

Comment: Have you implemented your copy constructor (and assignment correctly)? It's not apparent from your snippet hence the simple question..

Comment: How do you initialize _L_begin?

Comment: No, I didn't. I left it to compiler.
When I thried to add `operator=` to `JacobianCol` I got the followin error in xutility
__xutility(3133) : error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const JacobianCol' (or there is no acceptable conversion)__

Comment: the type should be const reference: const JacobianCol&.

Comment: `typedef std::map<int, Submatrix> _col_data;`
`_L_begin = _col_data.begin();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JacobianCol has the _col_data member. i.e, the input instance JacobianCol Y has a _col_data instance and _L_Begin of this is initialized with that map's iterator. When you return the result, a different _col_data member is created. Now, the _L_Begin iterator is copied from the original Y instance. That is why you get the observed behavior.

To resolve this implement the copy constructor, copy the map and the re-initialize the iterator by explicitly calling _col_data.begin() in the copy constructor

```
JacobianCol(const JacobianCol& aSrc_in)
{
    _coll_data = aSrc_in._coll_data;
    _L_Begin = _coll_data.begin();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying to implement this. I just thought there is any other compiler-based way :) Thank you

Comment: Unfortunately compiler cannot know that your iterator need to be 'copied' in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```
JacobianCol result = Y;
```

result._L_begin keep pointing to Y._col_data.begin(). When the object which Y is a reference to is deleted, result._L_begin keep pointing to that location, which is now invalid.

Comment: Yes, I've figured that out. What I'm asking is how can I manage this situation.